Unexpected vm behaviours
I recently started using ubuntu in a vm with windows as a host, but facing countless unexpected behaviour mentioning some below

Chopping of audio while playing some videos on firefox
When i open some application the window of the same keep clipping with constant black screen for indefinite time
Continous beep type sound from ubuntu after using it for a while

I did installed the guest addition provided neccessary resource based on my knowledge
8gb Ram, 128Mb Video memory , 4 cores of Cpu, 3d acceleration 

top - 15:28:16 up 30 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.84, 0.90, 0.64
Tasks: 256 total,   1 running, 255 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.9 us,  3.1 sy,  0.5 ni, 94.2 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st 
MiB Mem :   7941.4 total,   3457.2 free,   2811.8 used,   2141.6 buff/cache     
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used.   5129.6 avail Mem 


It doesn't seems to be a issue with the resources so what can be the possible issue and fixes
Ubuntu version : 24.04.1 LTS
